# How to get currency symbol by currency code?

Tags: magento-1.7

I can get the currency code from the order object. How can I derive currency symbol by using it? Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: If you found one of this answers useful, please flag them as correct answer.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Try this one:

```
Mage::app()->getLocale()->currency(Mage::app()->getStore()->getCurrentCurrencyCode())->getSymbol();
```

Comment: Please mark this answer as correct.

Answer (score 29):

Store currency code eg. **USD**

```
$currency_code = Mage::app()->getStore()->getCurrentCurrencyCode();
```

store currency symbol eg. **$**

```
$currency_symbol = Mage::app()->getLocale()->currency( $currency_code )->getSymbol();
```

store currency name eg. **US Dollar**

```
$currency_name = Mage::app()->getLocale()->currency( $currency_code)->getName();
```

Comment: This does not work in 1.7

Answer (score 6):

The following worked.

```
// store currency symbol eg. $ 
$currency_symbol = Mage::app()->getLocale()->currency( $currency_code )->getSymbol();
```

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
$currencyCode   = '';
$currency       = $order->getOrderCurrency(); //$order object
if (is_object($currency)) {
    $currencyCode = $currency->getCurrencyCode();
}
$currencySymbol = Mage::app()->getLocale()->currency($currencyCode)->getSymbol();
var_dump($currencySymbol);
```

Comment: Mage::app()->getLocale() will return the current locale object isn't it? What I want is get the currency symbol of the given currency code regardless of locale.

Comment: Please check once the code. It should work.

Comment: It won't work if you've set a different symbol in your locale. It would still return your default currency symbol.

Comment: @MagePsycho: Checked. It is not working.

Comment: Can you paste your code? I just tested and it was working fine for me.

Answer (score 2):

Using any given currency code you can derive the symbol using Zend_Locale:

```
$curr = new Zend_Currency('en_US');
echo $curr->getSymbol();
```

Comment: According to your solution we have to pass the locale to create Zend_Currency object right? What I expected was is there a way to get currency symbol regardless of locale? I mean by just passing the currency code can we get currency symbol in magento CE 1.7?

Comment: You can pass *any* locale to zend currency

Comment: Yes. See the docs http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.currency.html

Comment: My problem background is like this. I have several stores with several websites. I'm creating a php file which runs outside of the project and get all the order collection regardless of the store or any other factor. In that case if I get all details of an order I can get order total amount and currency code as separate values. I want to get the currency symbol and show the order total as a complete amount in my php file. So I cannot put whatever the locale I want. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Just pass the value in variable .. will return current currency format price

```
$Formatted_Price = Converted Price with Currency 
$Variable_Price  = Your Variable value
$Formatted_Price= Mage::helper('core')->currency($Variable_Price, true, false);
```